# HapiJS -- running the server with maximum memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am running out of memory doing some looping. I am suspecting that HapiJS is being run in some kind of restricted mode.

My development machine has i7 and 8GB ram, but in Hapi console I never see that Hapi uses more than 1GB.

How can I ensure that Hapi uses max resources when being run on my dev machine?
Or at least, set the memory allocation or something?

I tried looking for the settings but could not find it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a not a problem of Hapi, node.js has memory limitation as default, you can tune this limit, just run node with additional parameter:

```
node --max-old-space-size=8192 app.js // set memory limit to 8Gb
```

Comment: Great suggestion. I will surely do that. How can I do the same thing now running it via Webstorm?

Comment: if you run your app from Webstorm, you need set up Run/Debug configuration, there you can add node.js parameters

Comment: Great. Thank you for help